# Python ggplot2 - No Axis Named X for Object Type - When using "stat_smooth" only

Tags: python, ggplot2

I have a pandas data frame, sensors.  I have two columns of interest, let's call them "cur_time" and "reading".

cur_time is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS for the format, dtype: datetime64[ns]

reading is float64

When I plot using ggplot, I get a fine graph with

```
ggplot( sensor_vals, aes(x='cur_time', y='reading') + geom_line()
```

However, once I change this to...

```
ggplot( sensor_vals, aes(x='cur_time', y='reading') + geom_line() + stat_smooth()
```

I get an error

```
ValueError : No axis named x for object type <class 'type'>
```

This triggers from pandas/core/generic.py Line 361 _get_axis_number.format( axis, type(cls) ) if that helps at all.

Not sure why it has no problem plotting this, but has a huge problem with smoothing. Can anyone explain what causes it, and offer insight into a fix?

Comment: have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47754388/valueerror-no-axis-named-node2-for-object-type-class-pandas-core-frame-datafr

Comment: @Ruturaj I saw it, but it seems like a bit of a different problem to me.  I'm not doing anything that uses the group_by statement, I'm simply copying the ggplot tutorial for plotting data just using my own.  The code I give you, other than the initial reading of the data in, is really all there is.